# How to Overlay on top of Canvas (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

How can I overlay buttons, text, etc. on top of a canvas?

I have an activity:

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private GameView gameView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        gameView = new GameView(this, scrWidth, scrHeight);
        setContentView(gameView);
    }
}
```

with the following activity_game XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.exampl.proj.GameActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
```

All the drawing happens in the GameView class.

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
```

I tried to put in an ImageButton in the XML but it wouldnt appear I guess it's because setContentView focuses on gameView class.

Is it possible to setContentView to the activity_game XML layout and keep the GameView running with the ability to pass the params to the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Create a layout with a GameView and the other views you want in a single layout, then setContentView to that layout.